# How to protect against SQL Injection in Jaggeryjs?

Tags: sql-injection

I am working with **Jaggeryjs** now which is a server side **JavaScript** like **Nodejs**. When I tried the [example mentioned in the documentation](http://jaggeryjs.org/documentation.jag?api=rdb), They have provided simple example just like **Statement** in Java. So, I did some Googling but didn't find any convincing solution just like **PreparedStatement** in Java.

In that case following options came to my mind with their respective concerns

1. The DB approach mentioned in the database itself is with protection against SQL Injection

   **Concern:** Sorry to put this option, as I haven't tested it against SQL Injection. So just need to confirm whether my assumption is true or not.
2. Already provided approach
   **Concern:** If any other approach is already provided then please let me know, as I am naive to **Jaggerjs** and trying out all the examples
3. To build own API which would work like **PrepredStatemet** of **Java** with parameterized enforcing strict type checking and protect against SQL Injection
   **Concern:** What all character escaping I need to do to protect against SQL Injection just like we do with Cross Site Scripting issue by doing HTML encoding? 
   Here I have successfully executed some encryption algorithms using their already existing Java implementation, if in this way I need to contribute and create own API please let me know, I would like to make it as an opensource library for **Jaggeryjs**. This API then will contain the protection against [OWASP top 10 attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10) to develop secure products with secure coding standards.

Comment: What is your question? Sorry but I can't figure out what you are asking.

Comment: Why don't you test it yourself to see if it is vulnerable to SQL injection?

Comment: `db.query("SELECT * FROM person WHERE id=? AND name=? AND gender=?", personId, personName, gender);` something like that should produce querying with prepared statement.